# How to use virtualbox to simulate a sub network with the host as router?

Tags: networking, router, iptables, virtualbox, qos

I am currently working on QoS router functions using iptables and tc on Linux.
I would like to use virtualbox to simulate a computer plug on my router (The router would be the host)

Physically, I have the eth0 interface to the WAN and I would like to create a virtual interface eth1 where is plug my virtual  machine (Virtual Machine having IP 192.168.1.10 and eth1 having IP 192.168.1.1)

Like this I can use tc and iptables to try my QoS router function.

Could you help me to configure this M

Thank you.

Comment: The virtual machine is using Zenwalk-Core and the host is using Ubuntu 9.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look at this link, maybe it can help you.
[link text](http://muffinresearch.co.uk/archives/2009/04/08/virtualbox-access-guests-via-a-virtual-interface/)